# could not load URL AVPlayer not playing video

Tags: ios, avplayer

*Below two lines are for those who wants to use AVPlayer in their app.

This player works fine if i uncomment middle line in comments i.e NSURL *url and set the first line below comments i.e playerWithUrl:url , and comment the starting two lines.

*Below is My Real Problem, I need Help.

But i am not able to set URL the value to the player method-playerWithURL which is a first line below comments, and i am setting it through fileURL instance which i have created at starting in 2 line. IN the debugger it shows API path in *localfilepath. but when i am setting local file path to player through fileURL it shows nil.

But if i use middle line in comments i.e set *url for player everything works fine.
Help me to convert API into URL for that player property

```
 NSString *localfilepath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[managedObject valueForKey:@"clip_path"]];

 NSURL *fileURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:localfilepath]; //because  of this i am getting video URL but something @"file://" gets attached to it in the end thus not playing video URL because of that fileURLWithPath suggest something another way to fetch URL


//  videoAVURLAsset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:fileURL];
//   NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.example.com/example_clips/SHAINA%20NC%20NEWS%20X%20180516%201657PM.mp4"];

// created player here //

  player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];   //here i want to set the value which is in the *localfileurl

  AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];

  [self addChildViewController:controller];
  [self.view addSubview:controller.view];

  controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(10,80,300,300);
  controller.player = player;
  controller.showsPlaybackControls = YES;

  [player pause];
  [player play];
```

Comment: Do you have to do something special for using local resources in iOS. I know you have to do that with Android. So it may not even register the local file from your pc. Are you trying it on a actual device?

Comment: on simulator i am testing it, but on simulator it is playing videos if i give pass url in NSString *url format @MNM

Comment: anybody expert please help i am stuck . help will be appreciated

Comment: i have found the answer :)  at the end of the page i have posted complete solution

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [`[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/fileURLWithPath:) to generate the URL object from a local file path string:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:localfilepath];
```

Comment: now its not showing nil there at place where i was getting nil before it helped me in some way but still not showing video i think its generating the other new file see in console i am getting like this two values of client but we want only the first                     _clients __NSCFString * @"http:/example.com/example_clips/SHAINA%20NC%20NEWS%20X%20180516%201657PM.mp4" 0x00007fc830f50000                          _clients __NSCFString * @"file:///" 0x00007fc830cc0680

Comment: @vicky That's a different problem so ask a new question. This isn't an ongoing support call.

Comment: your help is appreciated  thanks but please help me in debugger console i am getting two values of client but we want only one @trojanfoe

Comment: i have found the answer :)  at the end of the page i have posted complete solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I play a video in iOS:
First create a web view 
Then link it to your view controller code
and then add this in the viewdidload()

```
    //add the video to the player
    let myYoutubeVideo = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/YNUEAxUGxyE"
    let myHTMLString = "<iframe width=\"\(videoPlayer.frame.width)\" height=\"\(videoPlayer.frame.height)\" src=\"\(myYoutubeVideo)?&playsinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
    videoPlayer.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    videoPlayer.loadHTMLString(myHTMLString, baseURL: nil)
    videoPlayer.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    videoPlayer.center = self.view.center
    videoPlayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Try putting the file in this directory

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
// where are you?
NSLog(@"Documents Directory: %@", [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);
#endif
```

This is the Documents directory for your app in the simulator. Then try to run it from there.
That way it should act like its pulling off the phone and not your local pc.

And give this a try too

```
file:///Users/codercat/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/YourProjectDict/data/Containers/Data/Application/(sample digit)7F53CFB3-C534-443F-B595-62619BA808F2/Documents/your file located here
```

This one is for Xcode 7 and higher

Comment: could you please tell me in detail which file should i put in directory @MNM

Comment: try putting the actual video file in it

Comment: You are pulling the video file from your local drive is what I got from the post. Is that right?

Comment: no i am pulling it from server in in this format initWithString:@"http://www.example.com/example_clips/SHAINA%20NC%20NEWS%20X%20180516%201657PM.mp4"];   see the middle line in comments in my code

Comment: and i have many videos in tableView which play in different view if i click a table cell

Comment: but i have many videos method you are using is not dynamic for multiple videos how you will use it

Comment: you could put it into a function and have you videos location as a parameter,

Comment: i have found the answer :)  at the end of the page i have posted complete solution  @MNM

Answer (score 0):

i have made it guys :) i found the answer :) this is a complete solution if you have many video URL's and you want to play videos from server directly in your player so you need to fetch all your clip paths properly first and use the following code

// here i am fetching all the url downloaded from server using core data managed objects

```
NSString *localfilepath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[managedObject valueForKey:@"clip_path"]];
```

// then on below line i am encoding it into NSUTF8StringEncoding format
      don't forget to do this otherwise video will not play as it wasn't    in my case

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[localfilepath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

// and below i have assigned url to the player and created the player

```
  player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];

AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];

[self addChildViewController:controller];
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];

controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(10,80,300,300);
controller.player = player;
controller.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
//player.closedCaptionDisplayEnabled = NO;
[player pause];
[player play];
```